# MySQL 8.0 Error Code: 3617. Latitude is out of range in function st_geomfromtext

Tags: qgis, shapefile, ogr2ogr, mysql-spatial

First, I have a **problem creating spatial index in MySQL 8.0**. Here the description:

1. I have a collection of several thousand species range maps (polygon & multi-polygon) which is provided by IUCN as a single shapefile.
2. I opened this shapefile in QGIS 3.6 and performed geometry check (Vector/Geometry Tools/Check validity).
3. All valid range maps have been exported into a new shapefile.
4. I imported this new shapefile into MySQL 8.0 via command line tool ogr2ogr.
5. For the ogr2ogr import I had to use the option "-skipfailures". Reason: ogr2ogr considered some of the range maps as invalid.
6. The remaining maps were imported into a MySQL table. And it seems all ok, at least you can run queries successfully. But the queries are slow, because MySQL always reads the whole table.
7. So I decided to create a spatial index and for that you'll need to set a SRID. And here the problem starts:

> “03:10:32    UPDATE gis.all_reptiles_innodb SET SHAPE =
> ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(shape), 4326)   Error Code: 3617. Latitude
> 124.241900 is out of range in function st_geomfromtext. It must be within [-90.000000, 90.000000].    0.000 sec”

I can't set a SRID because of problems with the latitude range.

A latitude of "124.241900" is obviously impossible, because latitude can only range from -90 and +90 degrees. It seems to happen quite often, that people mix up longitude (allowed range: -180 and +180 degrees) with latitude.

Additional information: QGIS shows these properties for the shapefile:

> ```
> “-181.5899672849999718,-54.0594466929999840 : 181.1581243180000911,71.1881355930000836”
> ```

Does somebody have an idea what went wrong and how I could prevent this error?

Something in the interaction between shapefile, QGIS, ogr2ogr and MySQL obviously caused problems. The map display in QGIS, however, seems to work fine.

I would like to import only valid maps into MySQL because I need the spatial data index. Without an index a single query takes >8 seconds and that is too slow.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 changed the way it does indexing. See https://mysqlserverteam.com/geographic-indexes-in-innodb/

Comment: The indexing changes are a good point. The problem is: When I use ogr2ogr with "-update" it will assign "SRID 0". And I can't change it after to SRID 4326 as needed due to the problems described. If I use ogr2ogr with "-append" it will not insert a single row into the table because it considers all data records as invalid. Anybody an idea how I can tell ogr2ogr that my source material has SRID 4326 and that I want to insert it the same way in the MySQL table?

Comment: you need "With MySQL 8.0 or later, the ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCE_SYSTEMS table provided by the database is used instead of spatial_ref_sys. "  as described https://www.gdal.org/drv_mysql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the hint! I played around with ogr2ogr and this seems to be the solution for the import including the correct SRID:

> ogr2ogr -skipfailures -f "MySQL" MYSQL:"gis,host=localhost,user=root,password=#123456789" 
>   -nln “my_tablename” -update -overwrite -t_srs EPSG:4326 -lco engine=INNODB my_shapefile.shp

But this sets only the SRID for each row. You have then to set an SRID for the column to create the spatial index:

> ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY SHAPE geometry NOT NULL SRID 4326;

Then you can create the spatial index:

> ALTER TABLE my_table ADD SPATIAL INDEX(SHAPE);